# Adding multiple coordinate from Firebase into ArrayList and create polyline

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, polyline

How to draw `polyline` from `Firebase` using the coordinate store in `Firebase`? I need to get the multiple coordinates from `Firebase` and insert into `ArrayList` then draw the straight polyline.

[image: My firebase look like in the picture.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To draw a polyline using the coordinates within your Firebase database, please use the following lines of code:

```
String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
        polylineOptions.color(Color.RED);
        polylineOptions.width(3);
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            double latitude = ds.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
            double longitude = ds.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);
            polylineOptions.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
        }
        Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```